# Assoc DOM elements with objects

Tags: node.js, dom, jquery-selectors

I have a JS object which is called Car and it acts like a class(has own methods, variables).

I wanted to select the cars with css like selectors which will ease my project, ex.

$('car .stopped .red').go();

To do something like this, I created a HTML and parsed it.

But it just gives me DOMElement, not the element that I created before.

My question is, is there any way to associate my car element with the DOM element? or is it possible to inherit the car element from a DOM element?

I'm doing this with node.js, and used cheerio.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, you can mimic the object model in a DOM model but for me it looks like killing a fly with a cannon.

If you store the cars in one array that you can easy filter this array with filter function as follows:

```
// prepare the functions
function isStopped(item) { return item.stopped; }
function isRed(item) { return item.color === 'red'; }
function go(item) { item.go(); }

// use them:
cars.filter(isStopped).filter(isRed).forEach(go);
```

Update: Just in case you really need to bind object to DOM elements: you can save object to element property and then access this property or save unique object identifier to the "data-" attribute. For example:

```
var document = parse('... <car data-id="10" class="red"></car> ...');

$('car .red', document).each(function () {
    cars[parseInt(this.getAttribute('data-id'))].go();
});
```